# if statements in C++ not working as expected

Tags: c++

Sensor_Fusion ranges from 3 to -3, the motor output is correct between 3 to -1, showing 1, -1 for Motor A and B respectively and then switching to the second `elseif` statement however when sensor fusion goes below -1 `MotorA` shows 1 instead of -1 and `MotorB` shows 0.996024 instead of 1. Does anyone know what the problem is?

```
if (Sensor_Fusion >= 1) {
    MotorA = 1;
}
else if (-1 < Sensor_Fusion && Sensor_Fusion < 1) {
    MotorA = Sensor_Fusion;
}
else {
    MotorA = -1;
}

if (Sensor_Fusion >= 1) {
    MotorB = -1;
}
else if (1 > Sensor_Fusion && Sensor_Fusion > -1) {
    MotorB = 0 - Sensor_Fusion;
}
else {
    MotorA = 1;
}
```

Comment: Please provide [mcve]. What is the type of `Sensor_Fusion`?

Comment: And the last `else` looks like it has a typo...

Comment: The first problem I see is a major run-on sentence at the beginning of the question.

Answer (score 1):

Your last line has the error, it should be `MotorB = 1;` not `MotorA = 1;`.